# SQL case that will use a current table

Tags: sql, max, case

I have a SQL statement that returns this result below, and I want that the num will drag the latest (by date) num that is not null. I can't get it right.

I want to add something like this:

```
case
   when num is null then max(num where date<my_date)
```

my result now:

```
Date  num
1.1   0
2.1   1
3.1  NULL
4.1  NULL
5.1   4
```

what I want:

```
Date  num
1.1   0
2.1   1
3.1   1
4.1   1
5.1   4
```

Comment: which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with an additional `SELECT`:

```
SELECT
    date
,   CASE WHEN num IS NULL THEN (
        SELECT MAX(num)
        FROM test tt
        WHERE tt.date < t.date
     )
     ELSE num
     END AS num
FROM test t
```

The idea behind the nested select is to go through all rows with lower date, and pick the `MAX` item. Note the table aliases `t` and `tt` used in the query to refer to rows of the outer and the nested selects.

[Demo on sqlfiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1b3ac/3)

Comment: The Problem is that the inner select is really heavy.. Is there any other way?

Comment: @DanaEzer You can optimize the inner select by adding an index on `date` or on `(date, num)`. Your task requires an inner select or a self join. It's probably much easier to replace `NULL`s in the code that reads the data from the query.